# Slash in last parameter in facebook canvas

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-canvas

I develop facebook apps and since this morning a new problem appears with URL parameters.

my URL is a simple "https://apps.facebook.com/appname/index.php?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=v3"
but when I want to get this parameters, the last one is returned with a "/" !

with previous example :

```
print_r($_GET);
```

returns

```
Array ( [p1] => v1 [p2] => v2  [p3] => v3/ )
```

how is it possible ? 
what can I do ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the official bug report, showing that it is fixed
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/567466826646137?browse=external_tasks_search_results_521619a38f9a76d24939387

I was suffering from the same starting from a few hours before you posted this question.

And after a day Facebook has fixed it.